# Showing of unvote in reputation history incomplete?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-history

Since an answer being unaccepted is `-15`, I assume that `0` is for an upvote on your answer which was just removed / cancelled; why doesn't it show the question link when you expand the score though? I don't see the question's number on my [audit page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) either.

[image: The bug on StackOverflow]

I did look at the "possible dupes", but none of them really answered my question and had more to do with up/downvotes on *questions* and not *answers* (which is what the rep. change in question was on).

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know, even if it's only a "you fail at reading comprehension", since that's entirely possible.

---

**Edit**

Ok, so I followed the FAQ's recommendation to [add a bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) for this question since I really wanted more views and above all, just an answer or two. However, the full time allotted to the bounty expired and it got just a couple more views and still no answers. I still have the same issue.

Since I've now lost the privilege to start another bounty until I build it up again, the only way I can think of "bumping" this question in the meantime is to edit it.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, more of a feature request as they probably didn't implement same mechanism for "unvoting" of posts like the one in place for unaccepting answers.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thanks, I didn't think of that so I added the `feature-request` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a downvote for an answer which I decided to remove and after doing a manual reputation recalc, I now have a similar 0 score, which has no link since the answer it would link to no longer exists. This is probably what happened with the other 0 scores during a system recalc after the author deleted the question.